# validation + repeater + hint text - validation issue

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a repeater and inside the repeater I have a textbox and button (together in an ASCX). The textbox is pre-populated with hint text, which is cleared on focus.

My issue is that if the when one textbox is filled by the user, and the user clicks the submit button, the hint text gets submitted inside the other controls.

I tried to do custom validation, but the validator tries to validate all the controls inside the repeater, and the other controls still contain the hint text, if it was not touched.

Since this is as ASCX, I don't want to go with a server-side solution that would force me to change the code of the ItemDataBound event of the page hosting the control.

Are there any client-side solutions or server-side solutions I can still keep encapsulated inside my ASCX?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using public properties to pass the data out of the ASCX to the parent page for processing, you could account for the ghost text there...

```
public property TextValue
{
    get
    {
        if (Textbox.Text != "Ghost Text")
        {
            return Textbox.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

For client side, you could bind to the click event of the button and clear the text if it matches the ghost text value...

```
$(function() {
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
        var txt = $(this).siblings('txtValue');
        if (txt.val() == 'Please Enter Your Name')
           txt.val('');
    });
})
```

You could register the script from your ASCX using a ScriptManager.

Comment: That is true, but I would like to also validate on the client side. Server-side only validation is a big no-no where I work.

Comment: You could use an UpdatePanel to ease the burden of client side validation or you could use a Validator control on the front end with an InitialValue set.  Would that work?